# Can I use RouteAttribute with regex constraint on segment with default value?

Tags: routes, attributes, .net-5

I want that requests with urls like `api/ru/home/index` and `api/home/index` would match the  action with route attribute. That is the segment with lang can be missed or receive one of the values ["ru", "cs", "en"]

Is it possible to achieve that with RouteAttribute? This doesn't work:

```
[Route("api/{lang:regex(^(ru|cs|en)$)=ru}/{controller}/{action}")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[Route("api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}")]
[Route("api/{lang:regex(^(ru|cs|en)$)=ru}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I guess as you have provided the default value for `lang` you probably want URLs like `/api`, `/api/ru`, etc also be mapped to the same action, that is why default values for `controller` and `action` are also provided.

**Upd**
Default values can be appended to the end of path only. Like:
`api/Home` -> `api/Home/Index`
not `api/Home` -> `api/ru/Home`

Take a look at [Url rewriting middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and check if you can implement substitution logic yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can achieve this with several RouteAttributes but I also have several optional segments with default value into the same url and it is frustrating to describe every case in route attribute. I want to figure out why this segments {lang:regex(^(ru|cs|en)$)=ru} doesn't work by itself especially the default value assigning. Thanks for the answer anyway!